# This is about the tor version 6.2

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Ah, i downloaded the tar version of Tor browser, made the start-tor-browser.desktop and others executable and run it. But it showed an error:

Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.

[image]

Comment: On the big window you see the "Copy Tor Log To Clipboard" button in a bottom left corner. Press it and paste Tor error log into your question - tis will help us to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: Along with the logs, 6.5 is the latest Tor Version, can you check that "6.2" was a typo? Also where did you extract the tar file to and how? Somewhere in your home directory? The various `.desktop` files shouldn't need to be marked as executable. Is it possible you've broken the permissions on the files?

Comment: I tried copying the logs but it couldn't be done due to some unknown reasons.I extracted the tarball on my home directory and yes i did change the permissions on the .desktop files.